# Security Report Comparison - Sonarqube Commnunity vs Enterprise Edition

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.1

We are currently using Sonarqube Community edition for static scanning of codes. Right now we are thinking of upgrading it to Enterprise Edition since we want a more detailed and comprehensive security assessment of our source codes. As per the highlights mentioned in the link below, the Enterprise edition has a "Security Report" feature.

https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/

Based on initial research, the content of this security report are [HERE](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/security-reports/). But upon inspection of our Sonarqube community results, it already has a security report section (see image screen shot below)

So, what we really want to know is, whats really the difference of security reports in Community vs Enterprise Edition? seems just the same

[image]

Comment: Could you say a word or two about what you _want_ regardless of if it's in any version?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson i want to know what exactly is the difference between security reports of the Community and Enterprise edition. We want to prepare our codes security-wise before they are subjected to penetration testing and/or VA

Comment: I wonder how do you get owasp entry...  I am testing at the moment enterprise and put intentionally class with security issues (sample from https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/coding_rules?languages=java&open=javasecurity%3AS5334&repositories=javasecurity) - none is reported in enterprise... community security sections are clean too...